# Instagram Scraping: How would I click and hold on an element, then release with another given function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, instagram

How would I click and hold an element then run some code, then after that code is done running, do mouse up and unclick?

I'm doing this for the Instagram story scraping project I've been working on and I need to click and hold an element while it copies some information into a list.

```
# Find element to click

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/span/section/div/div').click_and_hold()

# Run code while the click is still held

getting_more_info_while_held()

# After done running other stuff, release button

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/span/section/div/div').release()
```

This is just so that the story doesn't change to the next image or video posted while it scrapes some info.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic to click and hold, then release.

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(element, 1, 1).click_and_hold().perform()

 # perform your operations here

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(element, 1, 1).release().perform();
```